# How do you find the page index from the paginated scrollview?

Tags: famo.us

I've been trying to find a way to keep track of which page the scrollview is on. Here's my scrollview:

```
var scrollview = new Scrollview({
    direction:1,
    paginated:true
});

scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);
```

I couldn't find anything, so as a last resort, I was thinking of calculating the index with getPosition :

```
scrollview.sync.on('end', function() {

    var position = scrollview.getPosition();
    ...

});
```

But the values returned are strange:

```
135.99973778400908
127.17900173310437
79.18730021387734
119.25586098115863
119.13859297279127
142.1383322620501
81.44664852586043
95.12230013491089
```

There's no sequence to them, even if I set the index of an item to track `getPosition(0)`. So I can't really use this.

Is there any way to get the index of the current "page" of the scrollview when paginated is true?

Comment: I second this. Would be great to be able to go to the page index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current release candidate `v0.3.0-rc`, you can get the current (node) page index. The code below shows how this can be done at the settling of transition to the page in the scrollview.  This may change, because Famo.us is in beta at the time of this writing.

**[Here is the example code](http://jsbin.com/levej/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
scrollview.on('settle', function() {
  var pageIndex = scrollview.getCurrentIndex();
  page.setContent('Page ' + (pageIndex+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realized famo.us is still under so much development. Apparently the scrollview was all kinds of broken and is a lot of it is getting fixed in v0.3.0 which is due soon:

[link to changelog here](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/v0.3.0-rc/CHANGELOG.md)

So the indexing feature is added in this version and won't need any kind of workaround.

Comment: This still does not answer your question.

Comment: I'll add the code here in a bit, you're right I shouldn't just leave it up to the reader to go dig it up